# How to identify whether images contain driver's licenses or ID cards

Tags: image-recognition, classification, facial-recognition

Suppose I have a lot of scans of hardcopy documents, in the form of jpegs. Some of them are potentially scans of driver's licenses or identification cards. I wonder what would be a good way to identify those scans that contain driver's license/ID cards.

One thought I had was training a model or use an existing pretrained model that can detect faces. However, if the data set I have has a lot of scans of photos of people, it would cause false positives. So I am not sure how I might approach this problem.

Any thought would be much appreciated!

Comment: what was your approach to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make a detector/classifier to look for the text "Drivers Licence" or some very generic keywords related to license? As you mentioned images of people may be present in any sort of documents. Looking for text which is super specific to IDs/drivers license seem to be a better way.